# grant access to reorder in admin

Tags: nodes

I have a Drupal with some kind of users (admin, gestion etc.) only admin can reorder field with multiple values when I editing nodes.
Other user can't, the draggable picture not showed.
Have you any idea? I thinks it's one permission but I don't find the good one (and with all modules, there is a LOT)

admin view

[image: admin view]

other users view

[image: other view].

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure it is a permission-related issue. Is the file `/core/misc/tabledrag.js` correctly loaded when you populate your field?

Comment: It is when I'm on the edit of the node... :/ (When I'm log as admin, or gestion... but gestion can't use it)